# Do I have to call release on an objective-c retain class variable when setting it to a new object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

Say I have:

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *foo;

in some class.

And I call:

```
myclass.foo = [NSString stringWithString:@"string1"];
myclass.foo = [NSString stringWithString:@"string2"];
```

Should I have called [myclass.foo release] before setting it to "string2" to avoid a memory leak?

Or the fact that nothing is pointing to the first "string1" object anymore is good enough?

And in the dealloc method [foo release] will be called.

Comment: You should never ever ever use release on a property accessor like `[myclass.foo release]`.

Comment: And please read the Cocoa Memory Management Guide.

Comment: More specifically: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html) on *declared properties*:

> **retain**
>     Specifies that retain should be invoked on the object upon assignment. (The default is assign.)
>      The previous value is sent a release message.